# Using PCB and external antenna at same time for WiFi

Tags: antenna, esp8266, wifi, pcb-antenna

If you use a design with an ESP8266 is there a possibility to use an external antenna (u.fl connector) with a PCB antenna at the same time without using a solder bridge or jumper?

Generally speaking, is it a good idea to put both antennas in series or parallel for WiFi? I can imagine there is a software solution that will sweep both connections and find the right receiver.

Comment: Yes there is a possibility. If you put the antennas in parallel, then you need a ‘splitter’ to distribute the signal. Putting the antennas in series might be a bit of a challenge. As for a software solution, not likely without extra hardware. What is it you hope to achieve? Would it not be simpler to use two esp8266s? You really should go for the later model chips as the security on the 8266 is woeful by today’s standards.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a power divider on the PCB output and from that connect a PCB antenna *and* the external uFL coax. The *divider* part implies that performance *will* be reduced.

Beside of the trickery of a microwave power divider, the radiation pattern of such two antennas would be… peculiar, I think. You'll have some form of (unwanted) beam steering.

Personally I'd look for a chip supporting *two* different antennas (for diversity)